# What does super mean here?

Tags: ruby

I know that if you use super in Ruby it means call the parent's same method.

But in some code I see this:

```
def self.post(*args); handle_response super end
```

I wonder what the super means here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`super` invokes the superclass method; so `super` returns what the superclass method returns.

Here, the `post` method defined on the superclass is invoked and its return value is passed on to the `handle_response` method.